# Using Bitcoin Core Wallet, encrypted it, now it won't recognize password

Tags: bitcoin-core, encryption, passphrase, wallet-recovery

I typed in the password very carefully, the same 5 digit password I use on another program. I know and remember exactly what I typed, I didn't type anything incorrectly. I got an error message saying the password was too short. Then the program crashed. When I relaunched it, the wallet is encrypted but it won't accept the password that I put in. How can I get my bitcoins back and/or unencrypt the wallet?

Comment: did you upgrade your core software?

Answer (score 1):

Try to unlock it on console by using the walletpassphrase command (e.g. walletpassphrase (5 digit here) timeouthere)

Answer (score 0):

These fellows seem to be onto something: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=790407.0
, if you only have a ~5 digit password, you could easily brute force it (one way to be sure you're not simply mistyping, or had mistyped)

But we're not the only ones.